# How do I merge my code behind file in the solution explorer?

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side, .net-core-3.1

I am trying to create a code-behind file for my blazor application (Using .NET Core 3.1, Blazor-server-side), while it also shows up in the solution explorer as the razor file you can click open, and then see the razor.cs file in the tree structure.

I managed to get the funcionality to work, but it still doesn't show up correctly in the solution explorer.

As far as I know I am doing everything correctly, I even tried to use an item template, and that didn't work either. Whatever I try, they always show up as seperate files.

The file names are the same, except for the extension, the class inherits from ComponentBase, I have tried calling the class in the file FetchData or FetchDataBase, neither works.

My class file is called: 'FetchData.razor.cs' 
My razor file is called 'FetchData.razor'

Am I missing something? I am on VS2019 V16.5.2, do I need to be on the preview version for this?

Code snippets:
class:

```
public partial class FetchDataBase : ComponentBase
{
    [Inject]
    private CoordinatesService CoordinatesService { get; set; }

    protected IEnumerable<ICoordinate> coordinates;

    protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
    {
        coordinates = await CoordinatesService.GetCoordinates();
    }
}
```

razor page:

```
@page "/fetchdata"
@inherits FetchDataBase

<h1>Coordinates</h1>

<p>This component demonstrates fetching data from a service.</p>

@if (coordinates == null)
{
    <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
}
else
{
    <table class="table">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Test</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var coordinate in coordinates)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>@coordinate.Test</td>
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
}
```

Image of solution explorer:

[image: Example of solution explorer]

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

At first glance, your file names do look correct, so make sure that File Nesting is turned on in the Solution Explorer:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I did not know this was an option at all. I have enabled it and now it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Edit: Your file names look correct. Have you tried closing Visual Studio and reopening? What are the little locks by your files, is that source control?

As I change a file name, the files switch in solution explorer to become embedded in the file.

Name your file:

FileName.razor

[image]
FileName.razor.cs

Comment: The locks are indeed source control. I have restarted Visual Studio and my computer already. When changing the file name to something else and back it also doesn't fix it in my solution explorer

Comment: You might as a test try disabling source control, just so you can verify that is the culprit and report it to Microsoft.

Sorry, I didn't see your names were already correct when I posted. Someone here showed me the same thing you already have.

Comment: I've tried that just now, but even if there is no source control then it's still not working properly. There seems to be something else wrong. Are you also using a Blazor server side application? Which version of Visual Studio are you on?

Comment: Is there a Blazor Server app or Web Assembly? I have only used Blazor Server is why I am asking.

Comment: I'm new to Blazor, but as far as my understanding goes if you install the latest preview of vs2019 you should be able to use Blazor WASM